# How do you extract data from multiple websocket streams to use in a formula?

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio

The following code is attempting to obtain stream messages from "connections" set.  I'm trying to figure out how to extract two float values--one from each stream--to calculate a quotient.  The aggregated stream messages appear unordered and non-sequential, and my routine stalls if I declare global variables and attempt to populate them iteratively.  I'd like to be able to connect to multiple streams and produce live calculated values/results using the message data.  Please help if you can.  I'm new to python and asyncio.

Here's the code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

connections = set()
connections.add("mystream1")
connections.add("mystream2")

async def handle_socket1(url):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket1:
        async for message in websocket1:
            json_msg = json.loads(message)
            if json_msg["X"] == "A":
                value1 = float(json_msg["b"])
            if json_msg["Y"] == "B":
                value2 = float(json_msg["a"])
            print(value2/value1)

async def handler1():
    await asyncio.wait([handle_socket1(url) for url in connections])
```

Comment: The code you posted is calculating quotients from a single stream. How yould you like to calculate quotients from two different streams? Do you want to divide `json_msg["a"]` from one stream with `json_msg["b"]` from the other stream, or something different?

Comment: Also, what should happen when a value arrives from one stream, but not (yet) from the other: should a quotient be recalculated immediately, or should the code wait for the new value to arrive in both streams?

Comment: I guess that explains why I alway get 0 for one of the stream values!  Ideally I would like to connect to both streams simultaneously and then calculate the most up-to-date quotient using one piece of data from each of the most recent streams. I would like to constantly refresh the quotient as though it's a live value.

Answer (score 0):

You can funnel both streams into a queue, and have a separate function that pulls either value out of the queue and recalculates the quotient:

```
async def handle_stream(url, identifier, queue):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket1:
        async for message in websocket1:
            json_msg = json.loads(message)
            await queue.put((identifier, json_msg["value"]))

async def calculate(queue):
    value_a = value_b = None
    while True:
        identifier, value = await queue.get()
        if identifier == 'A':
            value_a = value
        else:
            value_b = value
        if value_a is not None and value_b is not None:
            print(value_a / value_b)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await asyncio.gather(
        handle_stream("mystream1", "A", queue),
        handle_stream("mystream2", "B", queue),
        calculate(queue),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think we're getting closer to what I need.  I must be doing something wrong though because nothing happens when I run your code even after I sub in all my streams, keys, and values.  To clarify: I need to divide B by A, where A is the value from stream1 where key = X, and B is the value from stream2 where key = Y.  Also, I'm a bit fuzzy about some of your variables: queue/identifier/json_msg["value"] (in handlestream), and value (in calculate).  Apologies in advance for my python newbieness.  P.S. I tested print statements all over the place and got no output.  Weird.

Comment: @Query13 If you get no output, then I guess the setup failed somehow. Did the original code run? As for variables, I'm not sure what is your question. Are the variable names somehow confusing, or do you not understand the purpose of the variables in the different functions? Do you understand what a queue (sometimes also referred to as channel) does in programming?

Comment: Yes, the original code worked.  I'm taking your example and starting from scratch adding line by line to see where the trouble is. I'll circle back.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you user4815162342.  I managed to generate the desired results based off your suggested code.  In case you're interested I've posted another question regarding the exceptions returned when I Ctrl+C out of the loop.